# I am not able to see one component in DOM if i include router-outlet directive. There is no error message

Tags: angular, angular4-router

*app.module.ts*

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
 import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
 import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'; 
 import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; 
 import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; 
 import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component'; 
 import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component'; 
 import { ServersComponent } from './servers/servers.component'; 
 import { UserComponent } from './users/user/user.component'; 
 import { EditServerComponent } from './servers/edit-server/edit-server.component'; 
 import { ServerComponent } from './servers/server/server.component'; 
 import { ServersService } from './servers/servers.service'; 

     const appRoutes: Routes = [ 
        { path: '', component: HomeComponent }, 
        { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent }, 
        { path: 'server', component: ServerComponent } 
        ]; 


 @NgModule({ 
declarations: [ AppComponent, HomeComponent, UsersComponent, ServersComponent, UserComponent, EditServerComponent, ServerComponent ], 
imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) ],
```

*app.component.html*

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a routerLink="/">Home</a></li> 
<li role="presentation"><a routerLink="/server">Servers</a></li> 
<li role="presentation"><a [routerLink]="['/users']">Users</a></li> </ul> </div>
 </div> 
<div class="row"> 
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2"> 
<app-home></app-home> 
</div> </div> 
<div class="row"> <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2"> 
<app-users></app-users> </div> </div>
 <div class="row"> <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2"> <app-servers></app-servers> </div> </div>
```

*servers.component.html*

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"> <app-edit-server></app-edit-server> <hr> <app-server></app-server> </div>
```

If I try below instead of nesting users, servers and home component in *app.component.ts*, I can't see server component in DOM. I want Servers component to be displayed.

*app.component.html*

```
<div class="container"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2"> <ul class="nav nav-tabs"> <li role="presentation" class="active"><a routerLink="/">Home</a></li> <li role="presentation"><a routerLink="/server">Servers</a></li> <li role="presentation"><a [routerLink]="['/users']">Users</a></li> </ul> </div> </div> 
<div class="row"> 
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2"> <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
</div> </div> </div>
```

Comment: So you want to go the server route but you dont see any thing display. Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes exactly@ Tony Ngo

Comment: does navigating to `/users` work properly?

Comment: @Scrimothy.  Yes it does navigate to /users properly.

Comment: It looks like you have both a server (singular) component and a servers (plural) component. Are you sure you're directing the route to the correct one?

Comment: @Scrimothy...Yes there are two different components server(singular & plural). Singular one is nested inside the plural server. Singular server is child component of servers(Plural). I think that i have directed correctly. Is there any way so that i can share my 3 components file? so that it could be reviewed for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

as your routes setting is that

```
>  const appRoutes: Routes = [ 
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent }, 
    { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent }, 
    { path: 'server', component: ServerComponent } 
    ];
```

your default route is HomeComponent and to show the others component you should navigate to

```
> /users
```

to view users and navigate to

```
> /server
```

to view your server component

Comment: Hussain... I have done so and also trying to route in URL. I do not get success either.           <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a routerLink="/">Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a routerLink="/server">Servers</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a [routerLink]="['/users']">Users</a></li>
      </ul>

Comment: Did you got any error in the console when navigating to another route?

Comment: i do not get any error in console while navigating. However, i can not see any more feature whenever i add in servers component. i can see only two lines as i saw before. I have added few more feature like input and button elements. But i can not see anything except two lines.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to have these as children of Appcomponent!

```
    const appRoutes: Routes = [ 
        { path: '', component: HomeComponent, 
         children: [
            { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent }, 
            { path: 'server', component: ServerComponent } ] }, 

        ];
```

Comment: users and server are not the child components of home component. i have created 3  separate components. Those are Home, Servers and users. Server has two child components i.e server and edit-server. Users component has only one child component i.e user.  Child components have already been nested inside their parents components through selectors.

Comment: Ok, so are u able to see these components by inspecting html?

Comment: Two lines are shown only in <p> and <h5> tags inside <app-server> whenever i inspect in browser development tool.